# uwsgi + django + nginx: Python application not loading

Tags: python, django, nginx, uwsgi

Following a bunch of tutorials, I wrote my first django app and then decided to deploy it on a linode server. Following [their tutorial](https://www.linode.com/docs/web-servers/nginx/deploy-django-applications-using-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04), I only got so far. The best I could tell, that was based on an earlier version of Ubunto and I tried some other things, including the uwsgi quickstart tutorial.

I got far enough that the command 'python manage.py runserver' would serve up my site and wanted to move on to using uwsgi to do the same.

It seems as though there is some environment variable missing. When I try to start uwsgi from the command line with:

```
uwsgi --http :8000 --module dynamicefl.wsgi
```

I get the following:

```
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.15 (64bit) on [Fri Aug 11 19:37:04 2017] ***
compiled with version: 6.3.0 20170406 on 10 August 2017 23:41:13
os: Linux-4.9.36-x86_64-linode85 #1 SMP Thu Jul 6 15:31:23 UTC 2017
nodename: roosevelt
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
detected number of CPU cores: 1
current working directory: /home/django/worksheets/dynamic-efl
detected binary path: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
!!! no internal routing support, rebuild with pcre support !!!
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI without its master process manager ***
your processes number limit is 3941
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uWSGI http bound on :8000 fd 4
spawned uWSGI http 1 (pid: 5998)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to TCP address 127.0.0.1:43637 (port auto-assigned) fd 3
Python version: 2.7.13 (default, Jan 19 2017, 14:48:08)  [GCC 6.3.0 20170118]
*** Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads ***
Python main interpreter initialized at 0x562bdad6fda0
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 72760 bytes (71 KB) for 1 cores
*** Operational MODE: single process ***
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./dynamicefl/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>
    from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
*** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (and the only) (pid: 5997, cores: 1)
```

A lot of the tutorials emphasize putting the path to the virtual environment in the .ini file, and I did (double checking with 'env' that I had the virtual environment right.) Here is the .ini file I'm working with

```
[uwsgi]
home = /home/django/Env/worksheets
chdir = /home/django/worksheets/dynamic-efl/dynamicefl
module = dynamicefl.wsgi::application

uid = www-data
gid = www-data
socket = localhost:9191
chmod-socket = 644
chown-socket = www-data

processes = 4
threads = 2
logto = /var/log/uwsgi.log
```

I have experimented with changing the chdir command some, as I'm not sure exactly where it should be pointing, but regarless of where it points that results in a similar line in uwsgi.log:

```
 -- no python application found, check your startup logs for errors ---
```

(Fun fact: I haven't been able to find reference to uwsgi startup logs)

If I go to the site in my web browser, I get an 'Internal Server Error' message.

I don't think that anything is getting as far an nginx, but I can include the .conf file and error logs, too, if that's helpful.

I know that there are a log of similar questions, but I've looked at them and they're not helping me. (Which is not to say that they don't contain the answer.)

Comment: I doubt very much this has anything to do with Ubuntu versions, or with environment variables. Did you install Django? How and where?

Comment: I did install Django from the command line in the virutalenv. I meant to include in the post (will add it) that 'python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000' serves up my site alright.

Comment: The bit about Ubuntu versions was that the linode docs referred to upstart, where apparently Ubuntu 16 uses systemd. (No idea what I'm talking about.)

Answer (score 0):

The [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/wsgi/uwsgi/) helped me out here. It turns out that my reference to the module was apparently wrong. I had a colon too many in the reference to the module. The corrected .ini reads:

```
module = dynamicefl.wsgi:application
```

What helped was resolving to battle it out until I could serve the site purely from uwsgi, so that I could stop restarting services.